# How to align SQL result set in tree structure hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

I have 4 result sets that need to form tree structure hierarchy as follows:

**Result sets:**

1. College
2. HeadOfDepartment
3. Teacher
4. Student

Now the hierarchy should be as follows:

```
College1
   HeadOfDepartment1
       Teacher1
           Student1
           Student2
       Teacher2
           Student3
   HeadOfDepartment2
       Teacher3
           Student4
           Student5
       Teacher4
           Student6
College2
............
```

What is the feasible solution to form this hierarchy?
 I have tried `row_number() over` the corresponding group to sort.
**Sample Data**

```
ObjectID    Stream      Category    University  Percentage  Subject
College1    Engineering             University1     
College2    Medical                 University2  
                    ObjectID        Stream      Category    University  Percentage  Subject
Belongs to College1 HOD1        Management          
Belongs to College1 HOD2        Technical           

                ObjectID    Stream  Category    University  Percentage  Subject
Belongs to HOD1 Teacher1                                                SQL  
Belongs to HOD2 Teacher2                                                Java

                    ObjectID    Stream  Category    University  Percentage  Subject 
Belongs to Teacher1 Student1                                            90  SQL  
Belongs to Teacher2 Student2                                            80  Hibernate
```

**Desired Output :**

```
ObjectID    Stream      Category       University   Percentage  Subject 
College1    Engineering                University1      
HOD1        Management              
Teacher1                                                        SQL  
Student1                                            90          SQL  
HOD2        Technical       
Teacher2                                                        Java  
Student2                                            80          Hibernate 
College2    Medical                    University2
```

Comment: I think SQL can never give you the result in hierarchy. So what is your expected output in tabular format.

Comment: yup, in a tabular format!

Comment: added sample data and desired output..couldn't format the resultset :(

Comment: Thanks for formatting my query! I hope sample data and desired output are giving some understanding for you people to guide my query.

Comment: Your sample data and desired output is unclear and unreadable - Please format your sample data and desired output with [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) -HTH ;).

Comment: was away for few days and I formatted in a possible way now.

Answer (score 0):

A way with using `union all` is:

```
;with combination as (
    -- Colleges
    select cast(id as char(5)) id,
        [name]
    from College
    union all 
    -- HeadOfDepartments
    select cast(CollegeId as char(5)) + cast(id as char(5))
        , '    ' + [name]
    from HeadOfDepartment
    union all
    -- Teachers
    select cast(h.CollegeId as char(5)) + cast(h.id as char(5)) + cast(t.id as char(5))
        , '        ' + t.[name]
    from Teacher t
    join HeadOfDepartment h 
      on t.HeadOfDepartmentId = h.id
    union all 
    -- Students
    select cast(h.CollegeId as char(5)) + cast(h.id as char(5)) + cast(t.id as char(5)) + cast(s.id as char(5))
        , '            ' + s.[name]
    from Student s
    join Teacher t
      on s.TeacherId = t.id
    join HeadOfDepartment h 
      on t.HeadOfDepartmentId = h.id
)
select [name]
from combination
order by id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9228)